# Laravel issue with create()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

I've just started some tutorial about Laravel and I got some trouble with this code:

```
 public function store(Request $request )
  {
        $product = $this->validate(request(), [
          'name' => 'required',
          'price' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);
        Product::create($product);
        return back()->with('success', 'Product has been added');
  }
```

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create()
>   must be of the type array, null given, called in
>   C:\~\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on
>   line 1374 and defined

I have no idea what I did wrong, I'm following this tutorial step by step

Comment: In your code, `$product` is the validation operation's results, not the product. You'll probably want something like `Product::create(request()->all())`.

Comment: It worked but I also need validation

Comment: You have validation. `$this->validate` will throw an exception if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing null into `create()`method because you are not getting request object here try this way

```
public function store(Request $request )
{
     $this->validate($request, [
          'name' => 'required',
          'price' => 'required|numeric'
   ]);
        Product::create($request->all());
        return back()->with('success', 'Product has been added');
}
```

**Alternative**

The way I recommend you to `Laravel 5.4` is like this

```
public function store(Request $request )
{
      $validator = Validator::make( $request->all(), [
          'name' => 'required',
          'price' => 'required|numeric'
    ] );
   if ( $validator->fails() ) {
    //error handling
    }

    Product::create($product);
    return back()->with('success', 'Product has been added');
}
```

**For Laravel 5.5**

As mentioned in chat you are looking for updating Laravel into 5.5 for Laravel 5.5 which is a stable release, I have found a good article [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/whats-new-in-laravel-55) which I read couple of months ago, they have described laravel validation in a decent way it will help you to understand more about it.

Comment: (1/1) FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)
in ProductController.php (line 41)

Comment: sorry I have done a typo here check the updated answer also I have attached an article for better insights

Comment: Thanks for article, but the code doesnt work too (1/1) BadMethodCallException
Method validate does not exist.

Comment: 5.4.36 someone suggested edit to my post and added those tags sorry

Comment: ok wait I am rewriting the answer I have answered it according to laravel-5.5

Comment: I'm wondering why composer installed 5.4 instead of 5.5 o.0. This can be because I'm using 5.6~ php (because of other procject that requires it)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156584/discussion-between-mr-pyramid-and-riten).

Comment: I don't think is there any reason for downvoting ?

Comment: please accept any of the answer which solved your problem to close this question and upvote any/all answer that has helped to fix your problem